# Finding the cell Value from Grid view in vb.net , front end asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datagridview

I'm stuck in this problem for long time now.
I need to get values from a grid view table in Double format.
I have used Asp.net as front end and Vb.net to write backend code

```
 Dim tmpMax As Double
```

```
 tmpMax = CDbl(Me.Dgv_Result1.Rows(1).Cells(columnName).value)
```

Here I get

```
*Value is not a member of System.web.UI.webcontrols.TableCell*
```

Well, Possibly i Tried this :

```
tmpMax = Me.Dgv_Result1.Rows(1).Cells(columnName).ToString
```

So that Once I get the value in string i can convert into Double.
But here I'm getting the actual column name but not the value from that column name.

It would be great if anyone in the community can solve this issue for me.

Thanks In advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how you make the grid.

If you use default (auto generate columns), or you use databound fields, then you can use cells. however, if you have custom templated fields, then you have to use find control.

FYI: Cells ONLY are by column number - you can't use a column name!!!

Here is a simple grid. We will display the integer "ID" column TWO time. I will do this, so you can see how to get the value BOTH ways.

So how you can get a value will depend on the kind of field template you used in the grid.

quick summary:
If you using cells collection then you can ONLY use column number (sorry, no column name allowed - always felt this was a let down!!!). You can however write a custom function that does let you get cells() by name.

But, at lest lets clear up WHEN you have to use cells, and WHEN you have to use find control.

so, this grid has a mix.

```
          <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" class="table" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID"   HeaderText="PK ID"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City"        HeaderText="City"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName" HeaderStyle-Width="200"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ckActive" runat="server" 
                            Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>'  CssClass="bigcheck" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID AGAIN"   >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" 
                            Text = '<%# Eval("ID") %>'  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Show values"   >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Row Click" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Note how for this example, I display "ID" two times!!!

So, our code to fill this grid is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim strSQL As String = 
            "SELECT * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName"

        GVHotels.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
        GVHotels.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub

Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using MyCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, MyCon)
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData

End Function
```

and we now have this:

[image]

Ok, for our row click event, we have this:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.Parent.Parent

    ' get ID (non template - cells colleciton

    Dim intID As Integer
    intID = gRow.Cells(0).Text
    Debug.Print("ID from cells collection = " & intID)

    ' get id from template field (item template).

    Dim tBox As TextBox = gRow.FindControl("txtID")

    intID = tBox.Text
    Debug.Print("Id from text box on grid row = " & intID)


End Sub
```

output:

```
ID from cells collection = 73
Id from text box on grid row = 73
```

So for autogenerated columns, or NON templated controls (datafield).

We have to count the columns and use a number for cells collection (as noted, you can NOT use the column name).

For a templated control, then you MUST use findcontrol, and you can't use cells collection.

So, take a quick look at your gridview markup, and depending on if you using auto generated, or databound fields (then you use cells, and ONLY number column number).

If you have as noted actual asp.net standard controls in the grid, then you have to use find control. and pull up the value. Note how have a check box, so we would have to define a control CheckBox, and use MyCheckBox.Checked to get the check box value. But again, if we used a databound field, then we use cells() collection.

Comment: Thank you so much for Quick Reply. I'll follow this and will try to solve it.